# the trait `scale_info::TypeInfo` is not implemented for

Tags: ink

I define a user-defied data struct in contract A(named `Payload`):

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, scale::Encode, scale::Decode, Clone)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(::scale_info::TypeInfo))]
pub struct TestData{
    pub n: u128,
    pub s: ink_prelude::string::String,
}
```

And then, I define a user-defined data struct in contract B, based on `TestData` in contract B

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, scale::Encode, scale::Decode)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(::scale_info::TypeInfo))]
pub struct MyData {
    td: Payload::TestData,
}
```

Contract A is compiled successfully. But contract B is not.

The error is as below:
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Actually, after posting my answer I realized that your code should've compiled in the first place (and it does if you define both struct in the same contract). Can you expand (so share more code) on the how you're importing `TestData` into your second contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically derive macros can only generate an implementation for a given trait on a struct
if **all** the fields of that struct already implement that trait.

If we take a look at your first struct we can see that the [`scale_info::TypeInfo` trait](https://docs.rs/scale-info/2.1.2/scale_info/trait.TypeInfo.html) is implemented for
[`u128`](https://docs.rs/scale-info/2.1.2/scale_info/trait.TypeInfo.html#impl-TypeInfo-for-u128)
and
[`String`](https://docs.rs/scale-info/2.1.2/scale_info/trait.TypeInfo.html#impl-TypeInfo-10),
so `TypeInfo` can be derived for your struct.

However, for your second struct the macro requires that `TestData` implements
`TypeInfo` - which it does not.

You have two options here. If all the fields of `TestData` implement `TypeInfo`
you can use the derive macro to implement `TypeInfo` for it. Otherwise
you'll have to manually provide an implementation.

That is:

```rust
impl TypeInfo for TestData {
    type Identity = ...;

    fn type_info() -> Type {
        todo!()
    }
}
```